# Why does my code print past the null character?

Tags: c

I have recently starting learning C through K&R, second edition. I am trying to solve Exercise 1-18 which has the following description: write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input and to delete entirely blank lines.

Here is my attempt (using `MAXLINE=10` to debug the program):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 10 /*maximum input line size*/

int getline(char[],int);

int main()
{
    int len; /*current line length*/
    char line[MAXLINE]; /*current input line*/

    while ((len = getline(line,MAXLINE))>-1)
        if (len>0)
            printf("%s",line);
    return 0;
}

/*getline:read a line into s without trailing whitespaces, return length*/
int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int i,c,j;
    i=j=0;
    while (j<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n')
    {
        s[j]=c;
        ++j;
        if (c!='\t' && c!=' ')
            i=j;
    }
    if (c=='\n' && i>0) {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c==EOF)
        return -1;
    return i;
}
```

So the basic idea is I keep filling reading characters into line, but also keep track of the position of (one-past) the last non-trailing blank character. I then put null character at this spot, with the idea that `printf("%s",whatever)` will actually print the contents of whatever until it encounters the first null character.

The program behaves as expected with 9 or less characters (including `\n` at the end). However, it keeps printing input with more characters and I don't understand why. For instance, my program with input `1234567891\n` actually prints back `1234567891\n` (yes, it even changes line!). What am I missing?

Comment: **Not related to your question** but don't you see how your `while` loop is just a strange `for` loop? **Probably related** you should try to write your code in a clearer way. I also recommend more whitespace to separate operators from operands, that helps when reading it. Using a `for` loop will probably help.

Comment: I also suggest better names for your variables, I had to read for a while before I realized that `i` was probably just `total_length`.

Comment: Are you sure `12345678\n` is the failing case and not `123456789\n`, and `MAXLINE` was 10? With `123456789\n`, your program processes nine characters in `getline`, then exits the loop due to the `j < lim-1` test. The last character read was `9`, so it does not appending a newline. It appends a null character and returns, and the main routine prints `123456789`, with no newline. Then it calls `getline` again.  Then `getline` reads `\n` and treats it as an empty line—because `i>0` is false, it does not append the newline character. It appends the null character and returns this empty string.

Comment: Thus, `getline` is designed to suppress completely blank lines, but the program fails because it uses `getline` to process both the start of a line and the continuation of a line, and `getline` has no way to know it is working on the continuation of an already non-blank line. You need to rethink the design.

Comment: @Eric Postpischl I'm confused. Why would `getline` read `\n` and not `c` from calling `c=getchar()`? Right after the first call `line` would be `123456789\0` no? Then the next call would read a new character, no? Why would the next call read `\n`?

Comment: Please answer the question: Are you sure `12345678\n` is the failing case and not `123456789\n`, and `MAXLINE` was 10?

Comment: No, `12345678\n` is not a failing case (I rewored the last paragraph to make this more clear). The program behaves exactly as I expected it to. `123456789\n` is indeed the failing case. And yes `MAXLINE` is 10, defined in the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the input is “123456789” followed by a newline character:

- The loop `while (j<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n')` iterates nine times. In the last iteration, `c=getchar()` has put `'9'` in `c`, and `j` is 9.
- Then `j<lim-1` is false because `j` is 9 and `lim-1` is 10−1, so the loop exits.
- Then `if (c=='\n' && i>0)` does nothing because `c` contains `'9'`.
- Then `s[i] = '\0';` appends a null character, and `getline` returns to `main`.
- `main` prints the buffer (`line`), resulting in output of “123456789”.
- Then `main` calls `getline` again.
- This time, in the first iteration of `while (j<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n')`, `getchar()` returns `'\n'`, and this is put into `c`. Then the loop terminates since `c!='\n'` is false.
- Since the loop terminated without executing any iterations, `i` is 0.
- Then `if (c=='\n' && i>0)` does nothing because `i>0` is false.
- Then `s[i] = '\0';` appends a null character, and `getline` returns to `main`.
- At this point, `line` contains a null character at its start. When `main` prints this, nothing is printed.

Conclusion: The design is defective. `getline` is designed to suppress completely blank lines by not appending a newline if the line is empty (`i` is zero during the test `if (c=='\n' && i>0)`), but it is called both for the start of a line and the continuation of a line that was not completely processed due to buffer size. When it is called for the continuation of a line and the line continues exactly at a newline character, it treats it as a completely blank line and suppresses the append of a newline.

One remedy would be to add a parameter to `getline` to inform it whether it is being called for the start of a new line or the continuation of a line, and then modifying the test `if (c=='\n' && i>0)` appropriately.

Another defect in the design is that, if a line contains blanks and/or tabs just before where `getline` stops processing due to the buffer being full, they will be lost, because `getline` writes a null character to mark the end of the non-blank portion of the partial line and returns to `main`, thus forgetting about the pending blanks and/or tabs, which might be needed because the later continuation of the line contains non-blank characters.

Comment: So basically when you call `getchar()` any subsequent calls will first return any extra characters the user put as input in the first call? I didn't know that, thanks for clarifying it for me.

Comment: @John: What? When the input contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and newline, then `getchar()` successively returns `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'`,`'9'`, and newline. That is all that is happening. `getchar()` does not care when your `getline` routine returns. The characters are in the input, and `getchar()` provides them.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. I had a misunderstanding about how `getchar()` works!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this is the whole answer, but I think you need:

```
 char line[MAXLINE+1].. this
```

This is because you are reading to 10, but your array needs an extra space for the null.

Also, I would try to improve the readability of your code in general. Possibly split some things out into functions, do some things as separate steps. You will thank yourself in 6 months when you've long forgotten what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Doesn't `j < lim-1` subtract 1 to allow room for the null?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, but I think this affects it: `if (c=='\n' && i>0) {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }`

Comment: @JL2210: But that overruns the array only if `\n` appears after 9 characters, which does not occur in the input cases complained in the problem. (One has 10, which is processed as 9 in the first call and 2 in the second, and the other has 8.)

Comment: It's very strange that he assigns both `s[j] = c` and `s[i] = c` when `c == '\n'`.

Comment: @JL2210: Actually, it can never overrun the array. If nine characters are read without seeing `'\n'`, then the first loop is exited (due to `j<lim-1`), and the character just read is not `'\n'`, so it is not appended, and the following statement puts the null character in `s[9]`, which is fine.

Comment: Does the s[i] = '\0' overrun perhaps? Remember c comes from the input not the loop. I suggest this because he is incrementing i before using it at the end.

Comment: @DanChase: There is no overrun. If you believe otherwise, put `if (lim <= i) { fprintf(stderr, "Gotcha!\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` just before `s[i] = '\0';` and find some input data that triggers it.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Interesting! I was trying not to put it into a debugger for him, and I am ending up cross eyed. what a mind teaser!